# How to do reconnection query to DB in protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor, azure-sql-database

I am using protractor cucumber framework.I have a  sql query to in my protractor script.In which i have used a connection close in 1 st query and trying to connect again for executing next query,in order to avoid max.requset limit to DB.my sql query is given below

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var config = 
{
 userName: 'xxxxx', 
 password: 'xxxxxx', 
 server: 'xxxxxx', 
 options: 
    {
       database: 'xx' ,
       encrypt: true,
       rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
    }
 }
 var connection2 = new Connection(config);

connection2 = new Connection(config);
 connection2.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err){
  connection2.close();
  }
 else{
  request3 = new Request("UPDATE Location SET  Location= 'LIVE' WHERE Id ="+ID,function(err,rowCount, rows) {  
     if(err){
       connection2.close();
     }
     connection2.close();
});
connection2.execSql(request3);
}  });
```

for the next query. i am trying to connect again same as like this.But the 2nd query is not executing and process get exiting.So do we have another syntax for reconnection?Thanks in advance

Comment: Recommend to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious-promises, which enable you to avoid nested callback in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to close the connection and the transaction pool.

This works fine for me.

```
 (async () => {
        const config = {
            user: 'User',
            password: 'iPg$',
            server: 'cp-sql',
            database: 'DBI',
            options: {
                encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
            }
        }
        try {

            let pool = await sql.connect(config)
            var envcode, testcode;
            let result1 = await pool.request()
                .query(`query 1 goes here`)
            // console.dir(result1)
            pool.close();
            sql.close();
            let pool1 = await sql.connect(config)
            let result2 = await pool1.request()
                .query(`query 2 goes here`)
            // console.dir(result2)
            pool1.close();
            sql.close();
            resolve(result2);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })()
```